# SQL Server timeout while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, timeout, command-timeout

I am experiencing a problem whereby executing a stored procedure to update a record in a table is resulting in a timeout error. I originally call my stored procedure from within an MVC3 application, which is where I first noticed the error.

However, using the SQL Server Profiler, I was able to copy the code that was generated by ADO.NET and run this directly on the database. I let this query run for approximately 5 minutes and it still didn't manage to return anything.

**Here are a few facts:**

1. The stored procedure has approximately 100 arguments that are being passed to it.
2. My MVC Application, SSMS and Sql Server 2008 are all installed on the same machine.
3. The stored procedure attempts to update a single row in a table containing about 5000 entries.
4. There was a trigger that would update the `LastModifiedDate` and `CreatedDate`, but I removed these triggers, and updated the EDMX to determine if there was an infinite loop caused by these triggers.
5. Our live server runs exactly the same stored procedure (using classic asp) as the one I am trying to run and achieves the correct result. Furthermore, the live server fails to run the same stored procedure under .NET
6. My machine fails to run the stored procedure for both the classic ASP and the ASP.NET
7. The stored procedure seems to fail only for a few of the rows, and others work perfectly fine.
8. I have tried changing the values of the parameters that are passed into the stored procedure
9. Other stored procedures work fine
10. There appears to be a lock on the particular table that the stored procedure was attempting to update, since executing other queries worked fine, even when waiting for this one to execute.

If anyone has any ideas on any other tests I could perform,or any tools I could use to determine the root cause of the timeout error.

Thanks.

P.S. Don't tell me to change the command timeout property, I have tried setting this to zero!

Comment: I have same issue with tables, where has column type is hierarchyid.

Comment: "The stored procedure has approximately 100 arguments that are being passed to it." Uh oh?!? Cannot imagine a situation where a procedure would get 100 arguments without violating the single responsibility principle.

Comment: what about a stored procedure which updates a row in a table with 100 columns?

Comment: ^ with 100 columns I might send it as a single argument in comma separated format.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things :

1. I assume you have already implemented exception handling in the stored procedure. If not, please do so, and try to get hold of the problem statement first. When you say, it happens for **some** rows, it might be due to **bad** data ? Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for information on how to do exception handling in `SQL Server 2008`
2. Have your tried finding out whether there is a dead-lock ?
   Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx) for detailed procedure and understanding.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into these resources now. I wasn't aware SQL dealt with exceptions

Comment: I added the Deadlock Graph Event to the Sql Server Profiler but I didn't get the Event coming up. Is there something I am missing? I removed the batch completed and batch started event class and added Deadlock Graph Event. I have left the Stored Procedure for 2 minutes now, but nothing has shown up. Does this mean SQL Server cannot detect any deadlocks? Furthermore, I have just checked the Logs and cannot find any relevant entries in there.

Comment: Have you first tried to catch exceptions ? Found anything there ? Would it be possible for your to post some code to get better understanding ?

Comment: I can't post it but it is a fairly standard stored procedure. It checks to see if the value of one of the input params is 01/01/1900. if it is it sets the parameter to null. Then it checks to see if there is any license information for this customer. If not, it inserts some license information into a table X. Then it proceeds with the update of table Y. if the customer's value for active is not 'Z' then update the active field of table Y